# How to add a delete button/icon for each product in the compare page?

Tags: magento-1.9, delete, compare, comparison

How can I add a delete function for each product on product compare page?

For example, if I added three products and click compare, then decided to remove any one of the products by clicking on a delete icon to remove it from the comparison, how can I add a delete function for each of the compared products on the product compare page. (The page that pops up)

Answer (score 1):

If you have compare item object then you can remove that item from compare using below helper class

```
Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getRemoveUrl($CompareItemObject);
```